# BigQuery "backend error" on loading

Tags: google-bigquery

We are having a number of backend errors on BigQuery's side when loading data files. Backend errors seem to be normal, occurring once or twice daily in our load jobs which are run every hour. In the last three days, we've had around 200 backend errors. This is causing cascading problems in our system.

Until the past three days, the system has been stable. The error is a simple "Backend error, try again." Usually the load job works when it's run again, but in the last three days the problem has become much worse. Please let me know if you need any other information from me.

Answer (score 0):

We did have an issue on friday where all load jobs were returning backend error for a period of a few hours, but that should have been resolved. If you have seen backend errors since then please let us know and send a job id of a failing job.